# Building a project for desktop target QT

Tags: qt, ubuntu, device

I've downloaded Qt for Ubuntu and installed it. However, when I try to create a new project it will only allow me to build for 'harmattan' targets, with no option to select desktop as a target build. I'm not sure why this is, does anyone know how I can select desktop as a target? I just want to build regular executables to run on my machine...

Comment: You probably downloaded the wrong Qt package. Did you download from [here](http://qt.nokia.com/downloads)?

Comment: Yes that looks like the place...downloaded the linux offline installer 32-bit.